# Rest Assured Exception when test fails

Tags: java, rest, groovy, rest-assured

I have a simple rest-assured test that is verifying this json comes be with the correct data for a call.  I am using rest-assured 1.8 and did swap the groovy jars for the groovy-all jar due to a known issue with 2 different versions of ASM.

My json the comes back looks like this:

```
{"account":"12345"}
```

My code looks like this:

```
package com.blah.tests;

import org.junit.Test;
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

public class AccountsTest {

public AccountsTest() {
}


@Test
public void getLocationAccount() {

            given().
                param("thingAccountIsfor","ABCD").
            expect().
                statusCode(200).
                body("account",equalTo("10")).
            when().
                get("http://machine:2343/rest/accounts/getaccount");

    }

}
```

When I run this matching the value i expect for the account it works fine.  When I put in a value that does not match I get a stack trace:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path account doesn't match.
Expected: 10
  Actual: 12345

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:399)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeFilterChain(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:759)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$invokeFilterChain.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1142)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.this$2$applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$this$2$applyPathParamsAndSendRequest.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:131)
    at com.jayway.restassured.specification.RequestSender$get.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.get(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:226)
    at com.tim.tests.AccountsTest.getLocationAccount(AccountsTest.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

I am running this inside Intellij.  I did try to move the groovy jars, back in, move the conflicting version of the ASM off of my class path and re-run it.  I got the same result so I don't beleive this has to do with using the groovy-all jar instead of the groovy jars that ship with rest-assured 1.8.

Does rest-assured throw an exception every time it has a test fail or is something wrong here?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it will fail by throwing `AssertionException`. You have two ways to avoid this:

1. Catch the exception with `AssertionError`.
2. Remove `expect().statusCode().body()` part and assign response to Response object and continue with desired tests by parsing it using `JsonPath` object as below.

   ```
   Response res = given().
       param("thingAccountIsfor","ABCD").       
       when().
       get("http://machine:2343/rest/accounts/getaccount");
   JsonPath jp = new JsonPath(res.asString());
   String account = jp.get("account").toString();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Response response = given().contentType("application/json")
                 param("thingAccountIsfor","ABCD").     
                .get("url")
                .then()
                .assertThat()
                .statusCode(200).and()
                .body("$", notNullValue())
                .extract().response();
  final JSONObject content = new JSONObject(response.getBody().asString());
  String val=content.getString("account");
```

cleaner option